# Page gives error kendo not defined when the scripts are referenced in the end of body section

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When I set the kendo script files at the end of the body tag I get error saying kendo not defined when the page loads however if I push the script files to the head section it works fine. So I am forced to move all the script files to head section. As per asp.net MVC best practice the scripts files need to be declared at the end of the body section for performance reasons. I am not sure why this doesnt work then ? Wont this be a performance issue ?

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/custom/app.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/angular.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jszip.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

**View**

```
<div class="requestgrid" id="requestGrid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CC.GRP.MCRequest.ViewModels.RequestViewModel>()
.Name("GridRequest")
.Deferred()
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(o => o.RequestID).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CountryCode).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.SalesOffice).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CustomerNumber).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProjectName).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ProjectContent).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ContractStartDate).Width("140px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Priority).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.NameOfResponsiblePerson).Width("170px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.ApplicantName).Width("120px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.Status).Width("100px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedBy).Width("110px");
    columns.Bound(o => o.CreatedDate).Width("110px"); 
    columns.Bound(o => o.ModifiedBy).Width("110px");
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Selectable(selectable => selectable
    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
    .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
    .Events(events => events
    .Change("onChange")
)
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(t => t.RequestID))

        .Read(read => read.Action("Requests_Read", "Request"))

    )
)


    @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()
</div>
```

Comment: There is a [defer technique](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#configuration-Deferring) where you can force the widgets to generate their scripts at the bottom.

Comment: `jquery-3.1.1.min.js` and `jquery.min.js`, are they different jquery scripts?

Comment: i tried using the defer technique. Not sure if I am using it correctly. It still generates the scripts at the top of the page. I have updated my post to show I am have used it

Comment: Did you move the <script> tags down? Defer is a technique that allows you to move your script references to the bottom. Then you add Defer() to your widgets. YOU ALSO NEED TO CALL @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts() AT THE BOTTOM (This is where the widget initialization will go).  If you are using MVC, consider doing [bundles](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/asp-net-mvc-5)

Comment: In my layout view , I had put the scripts at the bottom in the body tag.  Is the following line called in the main view where my widgets are or layout view @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts(). i had called it main view as seen in the post above. Yes Steve I am considering using bundling but want to get this first sorted and working

Comment: [Here](https://telerikhelper.net/2013/10/09/how-to-defer-kendo-ui-initialization-scripts-when-using-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-wrappers/) is a good technique for MVC. Add a `@RenderSection("PageScripts", required:false)` to your _layout. Then in any page with kendo widgets use the .Render() on them and add `@section PageScripts {
@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()
}` at the bottom of those pages.